# How to update dll-file without main program being restart?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

How to update dll-file without program being restart?

I want to create my "Updater" class. It's main idea is to
     check local(connected to executive file) and server dll-files, 
     and when newer version is available, copying server file to local.

**Code:**

```
Updater updater = new Updater(LOCAL_PATH, SERVER_PATH);
if (updater.IsAvailableNewerVersion)
    updater.Update();
```

Updater's ctor take two paths - to server dll and to local dll and calculate their Versions.
     Then I call a property IsAvailableNewerVersion - if it's true (available version is newer then a local), I call Update method.
     Main Idea of Update method is to copying server dll-file to local with overwrite, and say to user to restart program.

**Code:**

```
public class Updater
{
    private readonly string _localPath;
    private readonly string _serverPath;
    private readonly Version _currentVersion;
    private readonly Version _availableVersion;

    public Updater(string localPath, string serverPath)
    {
        _localPath = localPath;
        _serverPath = serverPath;
        _currentVersion = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(_localPath).Version;
        _availableVersion = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(_serverPath).Version;
    }
    public bool IsAvailableNewerVersion => _availableVersion.Major > _currentVersion.Major ||
                                           _availableVersion.MajorRevision > _currentVersion.MajorRevision ||
                                           _availableVersion.Minor > _currentVersion.Minor ||
                                           _availableVersion.MinorRevision > _currentVersion.MinorRevision ||
                                           _availableVersion.Build > _currentVersion.Build ||
                                           _availableVersion.Revision > _currentVersion.Revision;
    public void Update()
    {
        try
        {
            File.Copy(_serverPath, _localPath, true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to copying file - " + e);
            return;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("File was successfully updated. Please restart program.");
    }
}
```

1. Is there a way to check dll-files before they being used?
2. How to update dll-file without program being restart?

**P.S.**
I think to use server dll-files, but my program becomes dependent on the server that is not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really unload / change the assemblies in a running app-domain; so basically you have two options here:

1. use a launcher exe that does this work and invokes an *inner* exe to do the real work, shutting it down when complete (launching a new one either before or after the shutdown)
2. use multiple app-domains in a single exe, isolating where each loads from

The second approach is more useful for server applications, since you can handle the network IO in the outer exe and funnel requests through to the inner app-domain, just changing a single reference to swap between the two systems. However, app-domains aren't in .NET Core, so you should be aware that it limits your flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Is there a way to check dll-files before they being used?**

If you are using a single EXE, it depends on how you use the DLLs. If they are hard coupled to your app, I do not know any way on how to do so.

But if the DLLs are just implemeting interfaces of your core DLLs, you could load them using:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("path\orbital.dll"));
Type type = assembly.GetType("FullClassName");
object instanceOfMyType = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

This requires you to follow some design patterns, what would be good for your app. But if you already have several DLLs strongly coupled (that means, you added them as reference in your Visual Studio project and are creating objects as `var object = new YourOtherDLLNamespace.YorObjectInTheOtherDLL()`) then you will probably take a lot of time to change to this approach.

The good about this approach is that you could check the DLL version before loading it, copy a new version from a server (or any other method you find appropriate) and then load it.

**2. How to update dll-file without program being restart?**

Ok, lets suppose you made just like my suggestion on item 1. Once you loaded the DLL, you wont be able to Unload it. You could destroy all the objects using the garbage collector, but that won't change the way windows is loading it.

So the basic answer for a single EXE is no.

**Other solutions**

You could wrap your solution in other EXE that keeps constantly checking if the DLL is updated, send a custom event (so that your app EXE would now what is going on an take appropriate action before shutting it down), notify the user and, if the user wants to do so, then you could close the app. Then your other app wrapper would update it and launch the EXE again.